# Pipe Python command output to netcat without sending an EOF

Tags: linux, python, netcat

I have access to an external netcat server to which I am trying to send a large input. I am currently trying to do so with this command:

`python -c 'print("a" * (50000-64))' | nc www.host.net port`

Though it appears that the server is indeed receiving and processing the input, the connection does not remain open as the Python program running on the server immediately throws an EOFError. I was wondering if there is a way to send the Python input without including the EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a `cmd1|cmd2` command, the shell create a pipe and the pipe is closed at one end as soon as `cmd1` stops. Then `cmd2` after reading all the data, see an EOF.

You can type `(cmd1;cat)|cmd2` if you want to make the pipe still opened after the end of cmd1. But the command will continue making you able to type other things. You wont get the shell prompt again. (You can end with Ctrl D which close the pipe and send an EOF, or even CtrlZ which makes `cat` suspended).

Answer (score 2):

EOFs are not something that is *sent* in the first place – they are raised implicitly when the end of stream is reached by the reader (server), and the stream **always** ends when the TCP connection is closed, which always happens when the client `nc` process exits. You cannot have an infinite stream after the client has disconnected, and you cannot have a "permanent" TCP connection that would exist without a client process.

So in order to keep a TCP connection open, you need to keep the actual process running – for example, make a Python program that itself opens the TCP connection via `socket`, sends the data, then *waits* for something instead of immediately exiting (e.g. `time.sleep()` if you have to).

```
$ python3
>>> import socket
>>> sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> addr = ("192.0.2.3", 1234)
>>> sk.connect(addr)
>>> sk.send(b"a" * (50000-64))
>>> [do nothing, leave it sitting at the REPL prompt]
```

---

It is possible to have Bash itself establish the TCP connection as part of the interactive shell; it will then last until you exit the shell (or until you close the connection).

```
Open:
$ exec {fd}<>/dev/tcp/www.host.net/1234
Send data:
$ python -c 'print ...' >&$fd
Close:
$ exec {fd}>&-
```

(/dev/tcp is virtual, handled internally by Bash – it doesn't actually exist in /dev.)